# Bigcommerce Stencil: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 63

Tags: package, syntax-error, bigcommerce, live-preview

I have been seeing this error in my stencil console when I run `stencil start` for a while now. Does anyone know what is causing this or if there is a good solution?

```
Debug: internal, implementation, error
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 63
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.internals.getResponse (C:\ProgramData\nvm\v12.0.0\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\server\plugins\renderer\renderer.module.js:125:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:88:5)
    at async internals.implementation (C:\ProgramData\nvm\v12.0.0\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\server\plugins\renderer\renderer.module.js:40:20)
    at async module.exports.internals.Manager.execute (C:\ProgramData\nvm\v12.0.0\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\toolkit.js:45:28)
    at async Object.internals.handler (C:\ProgramData\nvm\v12.0.0\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\handler.js:46:20)
    at async exports.execute (C:\ProgramData\nvm\v12.0.0\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\handler.js:31:20)
    at async Request._lifecycle (C:\ProgramData\nvm\v12.0.0\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\request.js:312:32)
    at async Request._execute (C:\ProgramData\nvm\v12.0.0\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\node_modules\@hapi\hapi\lib\request.js:221:9)
```

I am using the Windows 11 beta but I've been seeing this back when I was on stable Windows 10 and we have also been seeing it on Mac systems as well, so I believe it is OS-agnostic.

Stencil info:

```
Node Version: v12.0.0
Stencil 3.2.0
```

And I am running these versions of atom to edit my code:

```
Atom    : 1.58.0
Electron: 9.4.4
Chrome  : 83.0.4103.122
Node    : 12.14.1
```

Let me know if other info would be helpful.

There is now a Github issue for this question. See here: https://github.com/bigcommerce/stencil-cli/issues/752

Comment: What are you trying to do when this error populates? For example, are you attempting to use stencil bundle or stencil push or is this happening on install?

Comment: When I run stencil start @HeatherBarr

Comment: Per our 'troubleshooting stencil cli' docs, this may be resolved by making sure that you are working in the subdirectory of the theme. You can check this by running the pwd command in your terminal.




If this doesn't resolve the issue, you may need to uninstall the cli & re-install. If you still get the issue after trying again, I'd recommend raising this as an issue on the cli repo. https://github.com/bigcommerce/stencil-cli/issues.

Troubleshooting docs for reference https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/installing-stencil-cli/troubleshooting-your-setup